# Hindi or Farsi numbers in django templating engine

Tags: python, django, django-templates, persian, hindi

I want to print {{forloop.counter}} with persian or Hindi encoding means to have "۱ ۲ ۳ ۴ .." instead of "1 2 3 4 ...". I searched a lot but I couldn't find any related functions. Would you mind helping me?

Regards

Comment: You've tried the `l10n` template library already?

Comment: 1) It's **Persian**, not *Farsi*. 2) In Unicode, there are two sets of *Eastern Arabic* numbers, **Arabic-Indic Digits** (`U+0660..U+-669`) and **Eastern Arabic-Indic Digits** (`U+06F0..U+06F9`).

Answer (score 6):

You could use a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters). I'm not familiar enough with Django's l10n library to know if they do this for you.

```
def devanagari_int(arabic_int):
    """ Converts an arabic numeral (ex. 5817) to Devanagari (ex. ५८१७) """
    devanagari_nums = ('०','१','२','३','४','५','६','७','८','९')
    #    arabic_nums = ('۰','١','۲'....)
    #     farsi_nums = (...)
    number = str(arabic_int)
    return ''.join(devanagari_nums[int(digit)] for digit in number)

# register your filter, and then:
{{forloop.counter|devanagari_int}}
```

Make sure you save your filter file as UTF-8 (or instead use the appropriate unicode representations).

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own template filter.

```
@register.filter(name='persian_int')
def persian_int(english_int):
    devanagari_nums = ('۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹')
    number = str(english_int)
    return ''.join(devanagari_nums[int(digit)] for digit in number)

@register.filter(name='hindi_int')
def hindi_int(english_int):
    devanagari_nums = ('०','१','२','३','४','५','६','७','८','९')
    number = str(english_int)
    return ''.join(devanagari_nums[int(digit)] for digit in number)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make a [templatefilter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) that converts a number to the appropriate encoding. You could then use it as such:

```
{{ forloop.counter|convert_to_hindi }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the django internationalization there is a library l10n is define in django

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom template tag.

To do so you need to create the following files assuming your app is called "myapp"

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        extra_tags.py
    views.py
```

Then add the following code in the file `extra_tags.py`

```
from django import template                                                             

register = template.Library()                                                           

@register.filter(name='persianize_digits')                                              
def persian_int(string):                                                                
    persianize = dict(zip("0123456789",'۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'))                                   
    return ''.join(persianize[digit] if digit in persianize else digit for digit in str(string))
```

Now you can simply do `{{ value|persianize_digits }}` in your templates and the digits will become Persian. This method also works for strings that are not numbers as a whole but include some digits in them, e.g. `10:27:33` which is a time duration.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the unicode version of template filter as follows:

```
register = template.Library()

to_arabic_number_trans = dict(
    zip((ord(s) for s in u'0123456789'),
        u'\u0660\u0661\u0662\u0663\u0664\u0665\u0666\u0667\u0668\u0669')
)

to_english_number_trans = dict(
    zip((ord(s) for s in u'٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩'),
        u'\u2080\u2081\u2082\u2083\u2084\u2085\u2086\u2087\u2088\u2089')
)

@register.filter
def format_number(value):
    cur_lang = get_language()
    if hasattr(value, 'translate'):
        if cur_lang == 'ar':
            return value.translate(to_arabic_number_trans)
        return value.translate(to_english_number_trans)
    return value
```

This works well for stand alone numbers, however any ideas about numbers in date?
like in
2 يونيو، 2020 
how can i get it right without messing with datetime objects!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to turn english numbers to persian numbers

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='persian_int')
def persian_int(english_int):
    persian_nums = {'0':'۰', '1':'۱', '2':'۲', '3':'۳', '4':'۴', '5':'۵', '6':'۶', '7':'۷', '8':'۸', '9':'۹'}
    number = str(english_int)
    persian_dict = number.maketrans(persian_nums)
    result = number.translate(persian_dict)
    return result
```